# Fill nulls to six-digit format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.id)
```

id is int property
How I can display this value as six-digit format.
For example, if id = 1. I want to display 000001, if id = 123 - 000123 etc.

Comment: `if(id.Length <= 6) var str = id.ToString().PadLeft(6 - id.Length, "0");`? Or better, check `DisplayFormat` attribute.

Comment: Add a `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:000000}"]` attribute to your property

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
`Model.id.ToString("D6")`

Comment: Can I do it via String.Format()?

Comment: String.Format is for string interpolation. it expects a template and a data that needs to be inserted in to the template. In your case there is no template you only need to specify a display format for int property so I think this is not necessary here, But if you still need it `string.Format("{0:000000}", Model.id)` should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830.aspx)

```
var newString = Your_String.PadLeft(6, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Format()`, i.e.

```
  String result = String.Format("{0:000000}", Model.id);
```

`D6` (from `6 digits`) is the other possibility:

```
  String result = String.Format("{0:D6}", Model.id);
```